# The text is cut on top on Android

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I use Firemonkey 10.4.1 and develop a mobile app.

No problem, on Windows (used to test) and iOS, but on Android my `TText` are cut (not always) on top

[image: cut 1]
[image: cut 2]

It's just some pixel, but I can't explain why sometime I have it ?

Comment: this is a bug in the Firemonkey. you can try instead to use the TALText located in https://github.com/Zeus64/alcinoe (will be today available to 10.4.2)